# Storybook MDX: Dynamic Meta Title

Tags: reactjs, storybook

How can I set a dynamic `title` property on a Storybook `Meta` component in a Markdown Extended `*.stories.mdx` file?

```
import { Meta } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';

// displays title as 'undefined' in sidebar nav
<Meta title={conditionalValue ? 'foo' : 'bar'} />
```

I also tried wrapping `Meta` in a higher-order component, which triggers an error: `Unexpected default export without title`

```
import { Meta } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';

export const MetaCustom = (props) => {
  const title = conditionalValue ? props.foo : props.bar;
  return <Meta title={title} />;
};

// mdx stories file
<MetaCustom foo="foo" bar="bar" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried creating a util function and import into the mdx and seems like it is working.

utils.js

```
export function generateTitle (condition) {
   return condition ? 'foo' : 'bar'
}
```

Component.stories.mdx

```
import { generateTitle } from './utils.js';

    <Meta
      title={generateTitle(true)}
    />
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up: As of **Storybook 7** dynamic titles are not allowed anymore. Neither as a function nor as a template literal.

```js
// ✅ string literals 6.3 OK / 7.0 OK
export default {
  title: 'Components/Atoms/Button',
};

// ✅ undefined 6.3 OK / 7.0 OK
export default {
  component: Button,
};

// ❌ expressions: 6.3 OK / 7.0 KO
export default {
  title: foo('bar'),
};

// ❌ template literals 6.3 OK / 7.0 KO
export default {
  title: `${bar}`,
};
```

[More info](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#string-literal-titles)